# Creating a button that adds 100 onclick

Tags: javascript

I started coding in JavaScript today and I am currently working on making a button that adds `100` to the `shark[0]` in the `shark` array. I'm using the arrays to store the data that I have.

The problem I'm running in is first saving the changed array and then secondly changing the array with the right amount. Tried to google it but could not find the answer. Thanks for the help.

```
shark = [1200, 993, 0, 0]
shark[3] = shark[0] * (shark[1] - shark[2])
shark[0] = sharkAdd(shark[0], 1++, 100)

function sharkAdd(value, x, hundra) {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('sharkAmount').innerHTML = shark[0], 10);
  value + x++ * 100;
}

shark.toString();
document.getElementById("sharkAmount").innerHTML = shark[0];
document.getElementById("sharkPrice").innerHTML = shark[1];
document.getElementById("sharkCost").innerHTML = shark[2];
document.getElementById("sharkProfit").innerHTML = shark[3];
```

---

The HTML (this is not the full HTML):

```
<button onclick="sharkAdd()" class="button button1" >Add 100 Sharks</button>    
<td id="sharkAmount">1100</td>
```

Comment: `<button onclick="sharkAdd()" ...` Where are the 3 arguments of the function?

Comment: there are several issues with your `sharkAdd` function. You never `return` anything from it. The parameters `value` and `hundra` are not used. You're trying to parse a number as if it was a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need. To save the data in client use [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). I will leave that part for you to implement.

```js
var shark = [ 1200, 993, 0, 993]

function addSharks()
{
    var sharkstoadd = 100;
    shark[0] += 100;
    shark[3] = shark[0] * (shark[1] - shark[2])
    document.getElementById("sharkAmount").innerHTML = shark[0];
    document.getElementById("sharkPrice").innerHTML = shark[1];
    document.getElementById("sharkCost").innerHTML = shark[2];
    document.getElementById("sharkProfit").innerHTML = shark[3];
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Resource</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Price ea</th>
          <th>Cost ea</th>
          <th>Profit</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>Shark</td>
          <td id="sharkAmount">1200</td>
          <td id="sharkPrice">993</td>
          <td id="sharkCost">0</td>
          <td id="sharkProfit">0</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick="addSharks()">Add 100 Sharks</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have got a bit confused while doing this, there are bits of uncompileable code, redundant things, and odd assignments of variables, too much really to dissect and explain here.

However, it's actually quite a simple job. I have commented the code in detail, to help you understand what each line does.

For simplicity I've omitted the bits from your original code which aren't directly relevant to the question.

```js
//this section outside the function will run immediately when your page is loaded into the browser.
//initialise the data array (as a global variable)
var shark = [1200];
//get a reference to the "sharkAmount" HTML element (as a global variable)
var sharkAmountDisplay = document.getElementById('sharkAmount');

//initialise the display with the current value from the array
sharkAmountDisplay.innerHTML = shark[0];

//code inside this function will run only when it's called (e.g. from your "onclick" event in the HTML)
function sharkAdd(value) {
  //"value" will be the "100" passed in by "sharkAdd(100)" in the HTML
  //now, add the value to the existing value and store it in the array
  shark[0] = shark[0] + value;
  //update the display with the new value from the array
  sharkAmountDisplay.innerHTML = shark[0];
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sharkAdd(100)" class="button button1">Add 100 Sharks</button>
<br/><br/>
No. of sharks: <div id="sharkAmount"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, i think this is the desired output for the question raised.

Comment: @AbhishekKumar thankyou. If you believe the answer is helpful, an upvote would of course always be appreciated just as much as a kind comment... :-)

Comment: yup, after adding comment i just forgot, please pardon me

Comment: I think this is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: @VigneshRaja the question says, quite simply " I am currently working on making a button that adds 100 to the shark[0] in the shark array.". My code does that. Perhaps you can explain how you think my answer can be improved in terms of meeting that goal? I would be happy to amend it.

Comment: Yeah. Maybe I had some advantage. I started framing the answer before having that advantage by guessing the result he updates on multiple elements at the end. But your answer can be easily worked out by the OP. He don't needed those complex calculations to do what you have achieved. So actually it lead to a XY problem. Peace :)